# Does anyone knows any games developed with emo-framework?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, game-engine

I am currently developing games for iPhone and Android platforms using [emo](http://www.emo-framework.com/). However, I am not sure if this is a trustworthy tool, because it seems to be a tool with amazing characteristics but I was unable to find any games developed with it. They do not have a very large discussion group, that's why I'm posting this question here, at SO.

If you have another experiences with this or another engine for cross-platform games development, I would be glad to hear it too.

There are very few free-of-charge cross-platform (iPhone/Android) game engines, so I believe this discussion would be very interesting. I am currently having a great experience using emo, but I would be glad to have sure that I am walking through a good path.

Comment: Man, I'm currently working with EMO framework to develop a game with physics. Well it's easy to use you can always give it a try.

Comment: I used emo in developing a game about 2.5 years ago. Unfortunately, my account is closed and all of my apps are removed from the market. The latest news related to emo is very old. I remember  read in their mailing list that the creator of emo will stop developing it. On the other hand there was another branch from the main repository for further development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard good things about the [Moai](http://getmoai.com) framework. They have a top rated iPad game for instance, called 'Crimson Steam Pirates'. Also it generates apps for the desktop (Mac,Win,Linux) as well as Android, iOS and Google's Chrome Web Store. You can do your development in either Lua or C++.

**EDIT :** [Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/) also looks good and like Moai is based around Lua. This one isn't free though (cost is US$350/year for Pro version - iOS & Android) but you can download the trial and develop your game in simulation mode to see how it feels. There seems to be an active community and good docs.

Comment: Thank you! That was a great tip! They are still on beta, but got a really nice software. Their support is way better than emo, but if emo was capable to build nice games, I believe it will be my choice.

Comment: No worries ... you might want to check out Corona SDK also - see my updated answer.